# nautilus connect to server - can not reach filesystem root

Tags: nautilus, mountpoint

Using Ubuntu-Raring I connect via 'Files/Connect-to-server':
ssh://root@myhost:mysshport/

connection works ok, but I am connected to '/root' on the target system and can not reach the filesystem root (I can not do a 'cd /' via the UI)

How can I specify my connect string so that the mount point is the filesystem root?
(Note: when I do the same under Win via Bitvise client I get a selector to chose '/' or '/root' so there does not seem to be a problem on the server side.)

Thanks a lot for any hints!

Comment: Bitvise is still a bit buggy and will disconnect your sessions randomly. Better try Putty which is reliable and stable

Answer (score 4):

nautilus always connects to the user directory of the server, and I did not figure a way out to connect directly to "/" , this is a working workaround.

If you specify a Path when connecting,

[image]

You can go back in the filesystem of the Server (or, for me, my iPhone).
See that you got the option to go back in the top.

[image]

Then you can click on "[user] on [the server IP]" (for me, "root at 192.168.178.22"), you get then to the root of the Server.

[image]

EDIT: I just found out if you cannot see the bar on the top to go back to root, you can press ALT+ArrowUP and you will see it.

Tested on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS with GNOME nautilus 3.10.1.

Comment: This works perfectly for me on Xubuntu 16.04 with Nautilus 3.14.3 as well.

Answer (score 2):

Another workaround to achieve this goal is that after connecting to the server using root user, press CRTL+L to make nautilus let you change the path, so you can change it to whatever path you desire (In your case you can simply remove /root from it's tail).

Comment: ctrl+L saved my life

Answer (score 1):

I don't know a real solution to this. BUT i'm using the following workaround. Since I always land in the home directory I just made there one or more symbolic links to where I would like to go. So to reach the root FS I did...

```
ln -s / ~/rootfs
```

Now I can access the root directory either by `sftp://user@myhost/rootfs` or by clicking on the link by hand from the home directory.